# SwiftUI Wrapped SearchBar Can't Dismiss Keyboard

Tags: xcode, uisearchbar, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I am using a UIViewRepresentable to add a search bar to a SwiftUI project. The search bar
is for searching the main List - I have setup the search logic and it works fine,
however I have not been able to code the keyboard to disappear when the search is
cancelled. The Cancel button does not respond. If I click the textfield clearButton
the search is ended and the full list appears but the keyboard does not disappear.
If I uncomment the resignFirstResponder line in textDidChange, the behavior is as
expected, except that the keyboard disappears after every character.

Here's the search bar:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct MySearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var sText: String

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {
        @Binding var sText: String

        init(sText: Binding<String>) {
            _sText = sText
        }

        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            sText = searchText
            //this works for EVERY character
            //searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> MySearchBar.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(sText: $sText)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MySearchBar>) -> UISearchBar {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
        searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        return searchBar
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MySearchBar>) {
        uiView.text = sText
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        //this does not work
        searchBar.text = ""
        //none of these work

        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

And I load a MySearchBar in SwiftUI in the List.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            MySearchBar(sText: $searchTerm)
            if !searchTerm.isEmpty {

                ForEach(Patient.filterForSearchPatients(searchText: searchTerm)) { patient in
                    NavigationLink(destination: EditPatient(patient: patient, photoStore: self.photoStore, myTextViews: MyTextViews())) {
                        HStack(spacing: 30) {

                        //and the rest of the application
```

Xcode Version 11.2 beta 2 (11B44). SwiftUI. I have tested in the simulator and on a
device. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` is not being called is because it is in `MySearchBar` but you have set the `Coordinator` as the search bars delegate. If you move the `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` func to the `Coordinator`, it will be called.

Here is what the coordinator should look like:

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @Binding var sText: String

    init(sText: Binding<String>) {
        _sText = sText
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        sText = searchText
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        searchBar.text = ""

        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood. That works. For others - in my case, I needed to remove the searchBar.text = "" line in order to keep the clearButton - necessary to remove the filter and return to the full list.

Answer (score 2):

The `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` call will be passed to the `UISearchBar`s delegate, which is set to Coordinator, so put `func searchBarCancelButtonClicked` there instead.

Also, when you are clearing the text you shouldnt set `searchBar.text = ""`, which is setting the instance of `UISearchBar`s text property directly, but instead clear your Coordinators property `text`. In that way your SwiftUI View will notice the change because of the `@Binding` property wrapper, and know that it´s time to update.

Here is the complete code for `MySearchBar´:

```swift
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct MySearchBar : UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var text : String

    class Coordinator : NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {

        @Binding var text : String

        init(text : Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }

        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            text = searchText
            searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        }

        func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            text = ""
            searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
            searchBar.endEditing(true)
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> SearchBar.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) -> UISearchBar {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
        searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        return searchBar
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}
```